# UIApplication sharedApplication openURL won't launch safari for certain URLs

Tags: ios, url, webview

It's puzzling but it works on some URL just not the one below.

http://m.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/flyknit-zoom-agility-women’s-training-shoe/pid-10950168/pgid-10926655

I'm launching safari from the app using this way:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.vigLink]];

Comment: I should clarify, self.VigLink is a URL string like the example I listed.

Comment: Encode your URL properly, I see you've an apostrophe in your URL which can break it.

Comment: Thanks!   Encoding the link using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding helped!

Answer (score 0):

Add "\" before ' to make it like "Women\'s-training-shoe ..."